# How Google deals with errors in C++

Tags: c++, exception

Google does not use exception in their C++ code base. For errors, they use a class called status than the programmer must check when it is returned from a function. Otherwise the program does not compile (link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOCElcMcFik at 41:34). I have a few questions:

1) Is there any example of that class on the web freely available?

2) That's okay for "void f()" that work with side effects that you turn into a "Status f()". But what if your function already returns a value? Google does not allow to pass references that are not const so you can't mutate a Status object given to you. So how do they do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This sounds a lot like Rust's [`std::option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) class. The Rust compiler will freak out and stop if you don't test the results of a function that returns those sorts of objects.

Comment: @tadman: My guess is that they hacked CLang for such a behaviour.

Comment: If you're planning to work for Google, I'm sure they'll tell you how their insanity works. If not, why do you care? Just write idiomatic C++ and leave them to deal with their self-inflicted misery.

Comment: One thing you can do is pass a variable by reference (or a pointer to that type) and assign your return value to it. Then return a `Status`.

Comment: @mstbaum: But how do you _enforce_ checking that `Status`?

Comment: @mstbaum: Passing a non-const reference is not allowed at Google.

Comment: @JBL sorry I missed that point.

Comment: @InsideLoop Isn't that just a apple/orange thing?

Answer (score 5):

From [Google style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Function_Parameter_Ordering):

> Input parameters are usually values or const references, while output and input/output parameters will be non-const pointers.

As the lecturer said Google uses a proprietary in-house compiler that has been rigged to throw errors when `Status` isn't checked.

Comment: Well that answers one of his two questions

Answer (score 0):

1) Like what has been mentioned before, you would need custom tooling to enforce such rules.  These could be code analysis rules that can be set to raise errors when failing.

2) There are ways to return multiple values in C++.  You can either return a pair where one item is the value you care about, and the other is a status object.  C++11 also introduced tuples for even more return values.  You could even write your own object containing all the returned information you might need, but this could end up being overkill in many scenarios.

Most likely, Google would have you pass in a pointer instead of a non-const reference.  I believe that they prefer this style because it forces the caller to pass in the address of an object so it is more explicit that a "reference" to the object is being used and that the object might be modified.

```
// let's a code reviewer know
// that a's address is used and might be modified
f(&a)

// requires the code reviewer to know
// the function signature to determine
// if the a is passed by value,
// const reference, or non-const reference
f(a)
```